# What is the best practice to pass pickles between workers in Dask

Tags: dask, airflow, dask-distributed

I'm trying to implement a data pipeline using Dask and Airflow.  I want to be able to add/remove nodes to an existing DAG, similar to middleware in NodeJS. My idea is to pickle the Dataframe so the next step can pick up and apply any transformation to it before pickle and pass on to the next step.  But with Dask parallel processing, the next node could be assigned to any worker.
I'm thinking having the scheduler and a few workers locally. When I have a big job I can fire up some EC2 workers to handle the job.
Any suggestion?

Comment: You can try it first then ask for code review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly serialize data for transfer yourself.
Dask will move data between nodes for you automatically, serializing data as necessary.